# navigator.storage returns undefined in firefox android

Tags: javascript, firefox

As per the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager) , `navigator.storage` is available on Firefox starting at v. 51 (after v57, it's enabled by default) and on Android, starting at v55.

While trying it out, I am getting `undefined`.

```js
zz = navigator.storage
console.log('Storage :' +  zz)
```

Firefox - v59.0.2
Platform - Android

Works correctly for Android Chrome and desktop Firefox/Chrome.

Tried to search for any bug in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=navigator.storage) but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, not to mention that it's inconvenient for us to have to go somewhere else to fully understand your question. Just include your code, right here in your question, via a "code snippet".

Comment: The docs. you link to say: *[1] Firefox 51 introduced NavigatorStorage, navigator.storage, and the StorageManager.estimate() method. These are enabled by default in nightly builds **but disabled by default in all other builds. You can enable these features by setting the preference dom.storageManager.enabled to true.*** Have you tried that?

Comment: From the docs - [3] The Storage API is implemented and enabled by default in Firefox 57.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm asking if you've tried the code anyway?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and found out it returns `undefined`.

Comment: `dom.storageManager.enabled = true` returns `undefined`?

Comment: `dom` is not defined

Comment: What about `storageManager.enabled = true`?

Comment: `storageManager`  is `undefined`

Comment: added to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1457973)